# Can we make Widget Options validaton in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, widgets, widget

I have exactly same question asked over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291470/can-we-make-widget-options-validaton-in-magento

I want to know is there any easy way I can validate my widget options input or I should write all validation codes by myself ?

Something like, check if the option is not a negative number or similar things.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only way i know to do this is by either doing the validation in the template using the js validator, or defining a custom block and writing validating in the block. Either way the validation tags do not exist and looking at Magento 2, it doesn't look like they will be adding them any time soon.

Comment: @Shaughn How can I do the validation for widget options ? Can you provide some examples ?

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: anyone can help ?

Comment: anybody ???????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at how Magento defined a helper block in the Mage_Catalog module.  In their widget.xml they define the helper block:

`<helper_block>
  <type>adminhtml/catalog_product_widget_chooser</type>
  ...
</helper_block>`

This leads us to class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Widget_Chooser` where you can see they define some JS to do special things on the widget edit form.  You should be able to add your own validation in a similar way that's custom to only this widget type.

Comment: So, there is no way currently right ? I have to implement it myself?

Comment: Right - the easiest way to do this will be to look at how Magento implemented it for the Chooser block.  You should be able to reuse most of the concepts in the above mentioned class.